# Unable to click on an element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm unable to click on an login element, i have tried many ways to click and its shown below. Please help me on this, source code is also given.

Source code:

```html
<div ng-hide="IsXmlPunchOut()" class="myaccount ng-scope">
 <div ng-click="Login()" class="myaccount-link">
  <div class="myaccount-label"> 
   <span class="icon-user-male" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="label ng-binding">Login&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I need to click on any of the one div element or else span element, which will open the login pop up window.

Codes tried:

```html
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.myaccount-label > span.label.ng-binding")).click();
  //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/div/div/div/span[2]")).click();
  //driver.findElement(By.className("icon-user-male")).click();
  //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/span[2]")).click();
  //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > div.wrapper > div.header > div:nth-child(1) > div.secondary-bar.ng-scope > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div > span.label.ng-binding")).click();

  //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".label.ng-binding")).click(); 

  //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".myaccount-link")).click();
  //driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div")).click();

  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.myaccount-label > span.label.ng-binding")).click();
```

None of them worked. Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: What error are your getting?

Comment: use actions class and try ie mouse move to element method.

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj: i'm getting no such element found exception

Comment: @DhirajDas Can you please explain me in brief about this action, or if u give me the code it'll be great

Answer (score 0):

Try mouse hover and click on element by css or xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cssSelector` as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.myaccount-link[ng-click='Login()']")).click();
```

Comment: again getting no such element found exception

Comment: @ChetanKumarT Make sure element is not inside any frame/iframe

Comment: I think @SaurabhGaur is right. If there is a no such element exception thrown, then it might be that the element is in some iframe. Or sometimes it can also be that a drop down menu hides the element before you try to click it. Which browser are you using?